# Flutter and Amplify/Cognito : How to update phone number in Amplify/cognito by using fluttter

Tags: flutter, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I use Amplify/Cognito in Flutter to handle user authentication flow.
I can update and reset a user password. But I do not know how to change a user's phone number.

Is it possible to update a user's phone number? I use currently theses packages :
amplify_auth_cognito: ^0.1.0
amplify_flutter: ^0.1.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your package from 0.1.0 to 1.0.5

```
 dependencies:
    amplify_auth_cognito: ^0.1.5
    amplify_flutter: ^0.1.5
```

From version 1.0.5, the API to update user attributes is now available. [Refer docs here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/user-attributes/q/platform/flutter#update-user-attribute)

```
try {
  var res = await Amplify.Auth.updateUserAttribute(
    userAttributeKey: 'email',
    value: 'email@email.com',
  );
  if (res.nextStep.updateAttributeStep == 'CONFIRM_ATTRIBUTE_WITH_CODE') {
    var destination = res.nextStep.codeDeliveryDetails.destination;
    print('Confirmation code sent to $destination');
  } else {
    print('Update completed');
  }
} on AmplifyException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}
```